# How do i call a member of a struct, that has been populated using a struct pointer function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I would like to know how to print the value of `char* word`from this structure.

```
  struct word_count_struct {
  char *word;
  int   count;
};
```

This structure has been given a value thought the function

```
struct word_count_struct *new_word_count( char *word )
{
    struct word_count_struct *new_word_count = (struct word_count_struct *)malloc(sizeof(struct word_count_struct));

    new_word_count->word = "Hello";
    new_word_count->count = 1; 

    return new_word_count;    
}
```

When I use `word_count_struct new_word_count( &word );` or `new_word_count( &word );`to call the function and `puts(new_word_count->word);` to print the member from main.c,

I get the error message

```
error: called object ‘new_word_count’ is not a function or function pointer
```

and

```
note: declared here
     struct word_count_struct *new_word_count;
```

What I am specifically not sure about is the function call, I know with any other function i would generally use the code `function_name(passing arguments);` but this function returns a struct pointer and there seems to be two names within the function signature.

If I do not use a function to assign value to the struct members, I am able to print out the value of new_word_count->word within main.c no problem, so I believe my issues must come from the function call. Thank you in advance.

Minimal, Complete and verifiable example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct word_count_struct {
  char *word;
  int count;
};

struct word_count_struct *new_word_count( char *word );

int main()
{
    struct word_count_struct *wordcountptr;
    char *word = "Hello";

    wordcountptr = new_word_count(word);
    puts(wordcountptr->word); /* print out the string "Hello" which was assigned to this struct member though the word_count_struct function */
    free(wordcountptr);
    return 0;
}

/* this function should take the value of the passing argument and assign it to the word member of struct word_count_struct and then return a pointer to that struct */
struct word_count_struct *new_word_count( char *word )
{
    struct word_count_struct *new_word_count;
    new_word_count = (struct word_count_struct *)malloc(sizeof(struct word_count_struct)); /* allocate memory for struct */

    new_word_count->word = &word; /* assign the memory address of passing argument to this member */
    new_word_count->count = 1;

    return new_word_count;

}
```

Comment: `word_count_struct new_word_count( &word );` is not C code.  Did you intend to write `word_count_struct *mystruct = new_word_count( &word );`. Please show a [MCVE], your question is somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
struct word_count_struct *wordcountptr;
char *word;
wordcountptr = new_word_count(word);
puts(wordcountptr->word);
```

this code compiles and runs but it is more or less useless because the `new_word_count` function is not finished.

**Question has changed...**

The problem is now here:

You need this:

```
new_word_count->word = word;
```

instead of

```
new_word_count->word = &word;
```

BTW your compiler should have warned you.

Complete function:

```
struct word_count_struct *new_word_count(char *word)
{
  struct word_count_struct *new_word_count;
  new_word_count = (struct word_count_struct *)malloc(sizeof(struct word_count_struct));

  new_word_count->word = word;
  new_word_count->count = 1;

  return new_word_count;
}
```

But with this approach you will most likely run into other problems because you only store the *address* of the word to be counted, but you probably rather want to store the word itself.
Instead of:

```
new_word_count->word = word;
```

you probably need:

```
new_word_count->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);  // allocate memory for word
strcpy(new_word_count->word, word);               // copy the word
```

Comment: I have change and changed my code and ran it, I am getting a segmentation fault. can you point out to me why the code is unfinished? I thought i had the function complete,

Comment: @TylerGreen 1. `new_word_count` doesn't do anything useful, especially you don't make any use of the `word`parameter. What is `"Hello"`2. You need to show a [MCVE], I cannot guess what code exactly you run. You show only code fragments in your question and very often the _actual_ problem is elsewhere in the code.

Comment: i have added a few comments to the minimal example to best explain the end goal

Comment: @ michael Walz. Thank you for the help! Question: I thought when calling a function that requires a pointer as its parameters, the function must receive a memory address as a passing argument. In this file i have used a function that passes a double pointer and `&word` worked. why does `&word` not work with a single pointer parameter?

Comment: @TylerGreen I think that's a candidate for another question.